# Update the ARM Template & fetch the Latest VHD Uri from blob to deploy VM

Tags: azure, automation, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

Use case:

1. Working to find out a solution to deploy/create VM with ARM template using Azure Blueprints.
2. Currently, having solutions where-in we can deploy VM using the existing VHD Uri.
3. Would need a solution nearest to find  wherein the ARM template can directly fetch the latest VHD URi from storage account(blob) and deploy VM.

Description:

- The blob would contain the latest weekly VHD Uri image build which needs to be fetched automatically with the help of ARM template parameters as a pre-defined set of values during deployment.
- As of now, tried working with various searches but couldn't find any with this related.
- Checked on automation account as 'runbook' if that can work, but looks like NO possibility
- Other thought process currently checking is whether, ARM templates can be updated weekly on scheduled job basis using powershell script inside the automation account as 'runbook'
- Spent much time, any lead/guidance would be appreciated.

Currently updated the flow as below:

- Created myself a Logic App which can fetch the latest VHD uri.
- So now needed guidance on updating the parameter of the ARM template file say e.g "osdiskvhduri"
- once parameter updated, I can try to link the logic app with runbook think of next stage.

Comment: If we want to get the azure blob URL, we need to know the account container and blob name.

Comment: Besides could you please tell me what you mean `The blob would contain the latest weekly VHD Uri image build`

Comment: Hi Jim Xu, thank you for quick response. Weekly VHD URI in the sense, the pipeline will store the latest image of OS disk in the storage account , using that VHD URI which comes  up weekly we have to Check for ARM template to fetch latest VHD uri that comes up weekly.

Comment: Any other lead/guidance on any viable options in azure?

Comment: I think you can write a PowerShell script to do that? First, get the URL from azure blob then create azure VM with URL.

Comment: thank you @JimXu. powershell script to fetch the latest VHD URI to updated the ARM template is what your suggesting? But in your second point, i didn't understand on "Get URI" then create azure VM, VM itself should get deployed using the existing VHD disk URI.. Can we continue on chat? if you can share chat link...

Comment: Hi. I suggest you still use PowerShell to create vm: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed

Comment: thank you Jim, Sure but hope that powershell which is used to create VM " will help me with fetching latest VHD URi from blob" as part of automation & that is what even i m looking forward...Because I have few other activities like domain join etc ,,each param cant be done separately so putting up everything on one box...